# Possible to see calling convention with gdb?

Tags: gdb, windbg, calling-convention

Windbg's `kv` displays calling convention information on x86-based processors. I've searched high and low but cannot find how to do the same with gdb. Is it possible? Is there another gnu tool that will show calling convention info? thanks

Comment: Most platforms supported by GDB only have *one* calling convention. I wonder what prompted your question in the first place.

Comment: Just personal edification. MSVC on x86 employs cdecl, stdcall, thiscall, and fastcall. This wikipedia article states that gcc on x86 may use cdecl, stdcall, and fastcall. So I was looking for a gnu tool that would show that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions